# Как работает background-size:cover

Tags: css

пол дня читаю про значение свойства background-size:cover. Вроде бы в голове отложилась мысль, что оно фон делает по длине и ширине блока, сохраняя пропорции, и если пропорции как то не получаются, то картинка урезанной получается. Но эта ничего не дает мне на практике такая трактовка.  Может я не так понял , потому что я понятие не имею как с таким определением в реальной верстки это использовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот сравните:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    width: 1020px;
}

.block {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.block_one {
  background-size: auto;
}

.block_two {
  background-size: cover;
}

.block_three {
  background-size: contain;
}

.block_for {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div>
background-size: auto;
<div class="block block_one"></div>
</div>

<div>
background-size: cover;
<div class="block block_two"></div>
</div>

<div>
background-size: contain;
<div class="block block_three"></div>
</div>

<div>
background-size: 100% 100%;
<div class="block block_for"></div>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за проделанную работу.

Comment: Sevastopol'
 мне показалось или cover по большей части пропорционирует, а contain по меньшей?